# how to parse limited records in json parsing in android

Tags: android

The fist thing I wanted to do was to add a progress dialog to my applications list activity. The activity isn’t time consuming (not much anyway) but you don’t want the UI to be unresponsive when the activity parsing the data from json parsing and embeding into the listactivity, gives a bad impression to the user.
please help me out

Comment: Your title has no relation to your question

Comment: Was it a question or tip to the users?

Comment: What is your actual problem/Question?

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask to show progress dialog while parsing the data

```
private class DownloadingProgressTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowDescription.this);

    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */

    /** application context. */

    protected void onPreExecute() {
         this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
         this.dialog.show();

    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try {
            downloadFile(b.getString("URL"));
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", "error", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

         if (dialog.isShowing()) {
         dialog.dismiss();
         }

        if (success) {
            Toast.makeText(ShowDescription.this,
                    "File successfully downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            //imgDownload.setVisibility(8);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ShowDescription.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

}
```